# Magento Force user to buy related product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing a website in Magento and I need to develop the following functionality.

1) Products are added in the back end as devices and services.

2) All the Products are displayed on the homepage together.

3) If a user buys a products (device) then he will also require to buy another product related to that product (service).

4) In short he can't proceed without purchasing service product.

5) So if user buys Device product then he will compulsory will have to select one of the service products available for that product.

6) Also a user can't buy the service product only.. To buy the service product he will have to also purchase the device product.

This is what I am trying to develop but have got stuck on this point.

I have tried the best way to explain my problem. Any help, ideas will be welcome..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You issue solves easily with bundle products.
Create the 'Device' product as a bundle product.
All services should be also products that won't be visible individually.
Add bundle option for the 'Device' that contains as options (selections) the services you need. (off topic: you can even set different prices for the same service but different devices).
Make the bundle option required.

Save the product- > reindex everything -> profit.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your answer but my problem is that I want to display the service product also in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, This free extension will solve your problem http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-bundle-product-s-bundled-items-images-19391.html